# Ошибка в программе-переводчике

Tags: python

Сделал программу исправил одну ошибку, появилась другая:

```
from googletrans import *
translator = Translator()
zapros = input('Введите название файла с расширением (пр. example.lang): ')
with open(zapros,encoding='utf-8') as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip().split('=')[1] for line in file if '=' in line]
result = translator.translate(lines, src='en', dest='ru')
result.text
```

а вот ошибка

```
  File "c:\Users\kiolk\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Python\ModsTranslatorMinecraft\ModsTranslatorMinecraft.py", line 7, in <module>
    result.text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В result лежит список, у списка нету метода text
Попробуй вывести result в консоль и посмотри что там

Ну вот, получился список объектов, и у каждого элемента будет метод text

```
for i in result:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: <googletrans.models.Translated object at 0x00000158D80E6E00>, <googletrans.models.Translated object at 0x00000158D814CE20> результ этого

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Вы на верном пути, просто расширьте ответ. Например, добавьте код как прочитать данные из списка. Не уверен, но предоположу, что как раз у объектов класса гугла будет метод `text`, но это уже сами проверьте

Comment: Ну вот, получился список объектов, и у каждого элемента будет метод text
Попробуй это

```
for i in result:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: спасибо! огромное спасибо!

Comment: @СергейОстровский напишите ваше дополнение в сам ответ, для этого нажмите Править под самим ответом. Не используйте комментарии для дополнений и строк кода. Это совершенно не читабельно

Comment: @СергейОстровский от меня + за отзывчивость. Я вам советую прочитать тему [Как написать хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)